# Pages module with different structure and layouts?

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

I have a complex project from database design point of view. There are about 10-15 different layouts for pages, some of them are static with images, some are landing pages, some requires a cover image at the top with different actions and so on. Each layout is .php file which handles the logic for each type of layout.

Bellow is a the structure of few pages

```
Home Page
   > Top cover
     > Text for banner 1
   > Features
     > feature 1
     > feature 2
   > How it works
     > step 1
     > step 2
   > Call to action
Special Product Page
   > Top cover
     > text for top cover
   > Features
     > feature 1
     > feature 2
     > feature 3
   > How it works
     > step 1
     > step 2
     > step 3
Exercise
   > Category 1
     > Sub Category
       > exercise 1
       > exercise 2
   etc ...
```

I could easily add the html for each page in the body of the page and get rid of some sub pages but my client has no html knowledge and I'm afraid he will break the design when he edits or creates new pages specially those with features and how it works. I want to make it as easy as possible for him to create/edit pages with just a wysiwyg editor. What's even worse it requires all pages to be searchable by users and I fixed that temporally with a `index_page` field. So pages with features and steps are not getting indexed.

I have a database table `pages` with the following fields `parent_id, layout, title, slug, body, index_page`. I'm using laravel and mysql database.

Another problem is that if you visit the url of home-page/top-cover/text-for-banner1 it shows the content of that page and it shouldn't.

Do you have any suggestions on how should I design the database or what approach should I take?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: @Epodax can you suggest an example?

Answer (score 0):

I’d say you want a pages table/model that defines the page title and where it sits in your site’s hierarchy. Pages could then have many “nodes”, where a node could be a text area, a carousel, a feature list, and so on. Your CMS should then work out what inputs to display based on what nodes a page has when a page is chosen for editing.

In terms of searching, I’d add a `getContentAsPlainText()` method that simply gets the plain text representation of all of the page’s nodes, and this is the content you would then use for indexing. So when you perform a search, it searches those blobs of text. You could put a listener on the Page model’s `saving` event to index the plain text version on save.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit the nodes part? will I create a relation table pages_nodes? and relate a node to a page it belongs?

Comment: thanks, I'll see what I get and I'll accept the answer once it proves to be a good solution ;)